# How to assign values to array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to copy an array into an array in object. I am getting this error

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
  Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.
```

My object is

```
newForm: {formName: string, formId: string, formAttributes:[], formResponses:[]};
```

I am copying this array-

```
formAttributeValues=["firstname", "lastname"]
```

as follows:

```
this.newForm.formAttributes= [...this.formAttributeValues];
```

This doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've to give proper types while using typescript. Here formAttributes should be of string[] type. Please refer to the code below for a more clear understanding

```
// newForm object type definition
let newForm: {formName: string, formId: string, formAttributes:string[], 
formResponses:[]};
// Assigning values to newForm
newForm = {formName: "", formId: "", formAttributes:[], formResponses:[]};
let formAttributeValues=["firstname", "lastname"]
newForm.formAttributes= [...formAttributeValues]
```